# Multi Column Select Menu with Header React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

Please advise if any suggestions or code examples for multi column select/drop down menu as per picture. Also, I'm looking for any libraries for React that can present such select menus with multiple column + headers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Material-Ui, a good way and prowerfull tool.

The documentation says everything.

To see the concept:
https://mui.com/components/data-grid/getting-started/#main-content

To see demo main component :
https://mui.com/components/data-grid/#mit-version

If something is not exactly what you want, you can customize, add other component...

Doc is solid and community is big with MUI